# Anti-aliasing in Android 2.2 stock browser

Tags: android, browser, antialiasing, android-2.2-froyo

Is the anti-aliasing during scrolling still implemented in the stock browser of Android 2.2? If yes, how can it be turned off programmatically?

Comment: This seems like more of a question for [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com) unless there's some kind of relation to software development. Are you just asking how to turn it off when using the browser, or are you attempting to do it programmatically?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure whether anti-aliasing is still enabled in the stock browser for Android 2.2, In 2.0, it was disabled, then in 2.0.1, it was enabled which in effect induces lag during scrolling in the internet browser. There is no option in the browser settings to turn it off (if it is enabled) so I want to disable it programmatically.

Comment: OK, I gotcha. I went ahead and added the word "programmatically" to the end of your question to make it a little more clear (feel free to clarify/expand on your own however you want, of course), but unfortunately I don't know the answer myself :(

Comment: Note this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14152 - In some cases Android browser will not anti-alias.

Answer (score 1):

AA is enabled in the stock browser, but it gets temporarily disabled when the view is being scrolled.  So when viewing a page you should see it is anti-aliased/smoothed  and when you are actively scrolling it you should see the aa off.

AFAIK there is no way to programatically enable/disable the AA behavior and the [WebView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) seems to support that.